# Ubuntu bq Aquaris 3g always showing roaming is on

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, 3g

I have a bq aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu edition. If I connect to the 2g service, all is well. I can speak on the phone, use my mobile internet connection, no problem.

If instead I try to use the 2g/3g service, I always get the roaming text in the notification bar, even though I never had active roaming on my prepaid card and the roaming setting in Ubuntu phone is set to off.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where do you live and which is your ISP?

It might be that it uses external services to provide 3G access. As an example, my gf lives in France and she has Free, who does something similar. She has to enable roaming to use the internet. Does the net work when you see the roaming notification?

Comment: I live in Romania, and the ISP is Telekom Romania, the phone found it nad selected it as active ISP, so it should not have any roaming active.

Comment: Fill the bug as suggested, that's the best thing to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all kind of searching the web for solutions I found out that my carrier (Telekom Romania) is transmitting 3G over the network of another carrier that was bought by the company some time ago.

It appears that their infrastructure is based on a kind of roaming between the 2G and 3G services and will only work on Ubuntu phones if you enable both 3G cellular data AND data roaming.

This way it works juns fine, and the roaming service that the system is detecting is correct AND free inside the Telekom Romania network.

Maby this will help someone when using Ubuntu phones inside Romania using Telekom.

Answer (score 1):

Can you report a bug about that on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-network/+filebug ?